# Spring Boot custom static resource location outside of project

Tags: spring-mvc, resources, spring-boot

How can I add a custom resource location that is on for example my D drive in folder called Resources.

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("D:/Resources/");
    }
}
```

This doesn't work.

This is my application class and the only other configuration file.

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Bean // for websocket endpoints
public ServerEndpointExporter serverEndpointExporter() {
    return new ServerEndpointExporter();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder bcryptPasswordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should state your location using the `file` prefix, check more [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html) . So it should be

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("file:///D:/Resources/");
```

Comment: Works. Can you tell me why the triple /// ?

Comment: The external directory location is defined based on the File URI syntax, the details are covered online e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Meaning_of_slash_character but in short, the given location is equivalent to `file://localhost/D:/Resources/`

Answer (score 0):

Try `/D:/Resources/`. Absolute path must start with `/`