# How to Run a spring boot jar with external classpath folder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How to Run a spring boot jar with external classpath folder,

i have config folder containing .property files. these properties files are required to start the server, how to specify the config folder path while running the jar by java command (basically using .bat script file);

[project structure in eclipes:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCJud.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot custom static resource location outside of project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32287982/spring-boot-custom-static-resource-location-outside-of-project)

Comment: Thanks for your remark, but i want it to do through command -cp , -Dloader.path

Answer (score 0):

command line parameters can be accessed as argument in main method. once you access the parameter as per below code you can use it for loading the resources.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String argument=args[0];
    SpringApplication.run(ShortUrlApiApplication.class, args);
}
```